# Multiprocessing in pandas dataframe for regex pattern matching

Tags: pandas, optimization, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am working on finding messages that match any regex from a list of unique regexes in a large dataframe. Here is the code:-

```
def match_regexes(message_body, regexes):
    for regex in regexes:
        if re.search(regex, message_body):
            return True
    return False

##Takes a really long time to run
in_debit_clean_df = ZERO_cashflow_IN_combined_df['message_body'].progress_apply(lambda x: match_regexes(x, in_debit_regexes))
in_credit_clean_df = ZERO_cashflow_IN_combined_df['message_body'].progress_apply(lambda x: match_regexes(x, in_credit_regexes))
in_balance_clean_df = ZERO_cashflow_IN_combined_df['message_body'].progress_apply(lambda x: match_regexes(x, in_balance_regexes))
```

Now above code thats relly long time to run (with progress_apply shows ~36 hours for the first call) and as I am working on a sagemaker notebook instance (ml.c5.9xlarge) computational power is not a problem. I want to be able to use multiprocessing and utilize all the cores to tackle this problem instead of going with the traditional code above for regex matching in the 'message_body' for a list of unique regexes. I am not very proficient in writing code for multiprocessing, batch processing and parallelization in general, so asking in community of someday can help me with this problem?

I tried some chatgpt naive multiprocessing code like this:-

```
def match_regexes(message_body, regexes, progress_counter):
    for regex in regexes:
        if re.search(regex, message_body):
            with progress_counter.get_lock():
                progress_counter.value += 1
            return True
    return False

def process_dataframe(df, regexes, column_name):
    total_rows = len(df)
    processed_rows = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
    start_time = time.time()
    
    # Create progress counter
    progress_counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
    
    def process_row(row):
        return match_regexes(row[column_name], regexes, progress_counter)
    
    # Process dataframe using concurrent processing
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(process_row, df.itertuples(index=False, name=None)))
    
    # Track progress
    elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
    print(f"\rProcessed: {processed_rows.value}/{total_rows} rows | Elapsed: {timedelta(seconds=int(elapsed_time))}", end="", flush=True)
    
    return results

# Example usage
ng_debit_clean_df = process_dataframe(ZERO_NG_combined_df, ng_debit_regexes, 'message_body')
ng_credit_clean_df = process_dataframe(ZERO_NG_combined_df, ng_credit_regexes, 'message_body')
```

but this seems to be running even slower than the non-parallelization code and seems to be not even utlizing all the cores and cpu utilization also doesnt fill up with this.

Computational power isn't a limit for me but I want to be able to use some sort of multiprocessing, batch processing, parallelization to get the very above code attached running faster

Comment: read notice : [mre]

Comment: Regexps are known to be slow. Sure you can use multiple cores, but using far more resources will certainly not be sufficient to make it fast and clearly not efficient in the end (so a waste for resources). A well written specialized code can be 10x to 100x faster than regexp (using the same number of cores), though it is less flexible and harder to write. High level generic codes have a high cost. There is no free lunch.

Comment: By the way, multiprocessing require to copy data in each process (very expensive memory wise and it does not scale, not to mention RAM/IPC are slow), or to share data manually (only possible with some specific types -- AFAIK not strings). Multithreading is limited by the GIL in Python. Most libraries do not release it (certainly not regexp ones). There is no other parallel model available in pure-Python (python has clearly not been designed for parallel computing in the first place and now suffers from this).